# Data misaligned when writing to SDHC card over SPI

Tags: microcontroller, sd-card, spi

I'm using a microcontroller (PIC18F26J50) to interface with a G.Skill 4GB microSD card.

- SD Card initialization is successful and I go from receiving 0x01 (Idle) R1 tokens to 0x00 (Ready) R1 tokens.
- Reading a data block works, I am able to read the location of partition 1 and read the first sector of that partition

However when attempting to write a block, I never see a response token. Upon dumping the raw blocks on the card. I see that the data did indeed write but it is not aligned properly...the best way to explain is with an actual picture

[image: This should be filled with 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, and so on up to 0xFF before repeating]

*This should be filled with 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, and so on up to 0xFF before repeating*

This card works absolutely fine in windows. And I'm able to read and write data to it properly.

Investigating, I find that the response I get is 0XCA, if you right-shift that you get 0xE5, a proper response token. The data itself is misaligned one to the left. Additionally, it appears that the two dummy bytes and the token were also written. Correcting for the shift you get:

```
FF FF FE 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C
```

So I removed the code to write the 2 dummy bytes and the 0xFE token, and holy s*#$ the card starts writing data IMMEDIATELY after the command, which I believe violates spec! Can anyone confirm if this is intended behavior for SDHC cards? Or is this card just running a really s*#$ty SD controller? (The latter I suspect because I have a 16GB card which is working fine)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem, which turned out not to be a problem with the SD card, but with my SPI interfacing.

The particular chip I was using (Freescale KL03) will retain the current received byte in the data buffer until you read it, even after you have started sending the next one. I was out of sync, so that each time I was writing an SPI byte, waiting for transmission and then reading from the buffer, I was actually getting the previous result and not the current one. As a consequence there was a single byte lag in every SPI transaction.

Thus, my scope revealed that I was exchanging the following with the card:

```
MOSI: 58 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 7E nn nn nn ...
MISO: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 FF FF FF FF FF ...
```

which resulted in the misalignment you encountered. It should have been like this:

```
MOSI: 58 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 7E nn nn nn nn ...
MISO: FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 00 FF FF FF FF FF ...
```

In summary, ensure that you are sending the 7E **immediately after** the 00 response to your write command.